# Attempting to set multiple values of a private field of int array through a public property outside of its class

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, field

I'm attempting to set a private field of an array of ints from outside the class through a public property accessor. I'm almost certain the problem is my lack of knowledge of the syntax to get this done. I've figured out how to set individual values if I specify the index for the array when accessing the property through the object. Here is what I have so far.

My class below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace paramRefVal
{
    class ParamaterTest
    {
        private int[] _ints = new int[5];
        private int _i;

        public int[] Ints
        {
            get { return _ints; }
            set { _ints = value; }
        }

        public int I
        {
            get { return _i; }
            set { _i = value; }
        }

        public void SomeFunction(int[] Ints, int I)
        {
            Ints[0] = 100;
            I = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace paramRefVal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParamaterTest paramTest = new ParamaterTest();
            paramTest.I = 0;
            paramTest.Ints[0] = 99;
            Console.WriteLine("Ints[0] = {0}", paramTest.Ints[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("I = {0}", paramTest.I);
            Console.WriteLine("Calling SomeFunction...");
            paramTest.SomeFunction(paramTest.Ints, paramTest.I);
            Console.WriteLine("Ints[0] = {0}", paramTest.Ints[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("I = {0}", paramTest.I);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The line I'm interested in is

```
paramTest.Ints[0] = 99;
```

I've attempted to set multiple values like so to no avail.

```
paramTest.Ints[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I'm getting two compilation errors. "The type or namespace name 'paramTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" without the quotes.

And secondly. "Identifier expected" without the quotes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your code works in my VS2012, no compiler errors about `paramTest` that is.

Comment: Make the "class ParamaterTest" -> "public class ParamaterTest" to cure the first error.

Comment: C. Lang. Make note that I stated I circumvented the issue and the problem is stated in a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
paramTest.Ints = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
paramTest.Ints = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

If you want to use the array initializer, you can do it this way:

```
int[] ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
paramTest.Ints = ints;
```

I don't get any compilation error about the type, though. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I included the new keyword everything was honkey dorey. Much appreciated Eve! In regards to the type, maybe we're on different versions of the IDE? I'm using VS 2012 in Windows 8. Either way the new keyword fixed it. Thanks again.